# How do you read from a ifstream asynchronously in C++?

Tags: c++, asynchronous, stream, pipe

The ifstream is reading from a UNIX pipe, currently the communication is done by sending a signal to the reading application, but I would like to get rid of the signals and use proper async io.

In C I would use the select() function with a timeout, so I could react immediately when there is something to read, and waith for IO otherwise.

In C++ I can't access the fd of the file, so I can't use select(). What's the most reasonable approach to doing this? Do I have to use some sort of Boost library, or can this be done using the standard C++ libraries?

Comment: I'm afraid that "most reasonable" is going to be mostly opinion-based, and thusly off-topic here. I have my own approach which I used before and I think is the best solution. Others will disagree, and advocate for their take on this. There are multiple issues here in play: lack of access to the underlying file descriptor. One can use their own subclass of `std::streambuf` to deal with it. But then the other problem will be that you can't just do a `select()` any time you feel like reading, without checking for buffered stuff in the streambuf (subclass) first.

Comment: Too bad that the interesting answers are based on opinions. If I knew what the best way would be, then I wouldn't ask. I don't have experience with boost or async streams, hence the question. If I could do it without streams, then using select seems to be 1000x easier than getting to know boost and it's parts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::ifstream` does not support asynchronous operations, it is designed for synchronous IO. You could build async IO around it using additional threads and IO queue, but in general this is not a good idea for efficiency reasons.

For asynchronous IO you might want to look at [Boost.ASIO](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html), in particular its [`stream_descriptor`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/posix__stream_descriptor.html), which can be used to adopt arbitrary stream file descriptors like pipes.